# How to open a MODAL with REACT because what I'm doing is not working and the data is coming back AFTER I call the openModal() function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have code with REACT, and I'm trying to open a modal using REACT. I'm NOT a REACT programmer but Angular. That being said, however, I'm not doing too badly.

Here are the issues:

[image: How the data comes back AFTER openModal is called]

Now the code:

```
export const TableActions = (props) => {
...
  let messageObj = object
  let modalMessage = object;
  let titleMsg = '';
  const { row, userId, setShowCIQ, showCIQ, siteDetails, setShowMessageModal } = props
  const [setCancelValues] = useState(null)
...
  const { mutate: getMessages } = useMutation((requestid) => getSomeMessages(requestid), {
    onSuccess: (res) => {
      console.log('RES MESSAGES: ', res.messages),
        messageObj = res.messages
    },
    onError: (e) => toastEachError(e)
  })
...
  const handleGetMessages = async (e) => {
    const requestid = row.itential_cfg_header_id
    messageObj = getMessages(requestid) // THIS gets the messages but it's happening LATER
    console.log("REQID: ", requestid);
    if (requestid) {
      console.log('Message OBJ: ', messageObj)
      if (messageObj) {
        console.log("MSG OBJ: ", messageObj);
      } else {
        console.log("NO MESSAGE OBJ YET!", e);
      }
      openModal(); // THIS HAPPENS BUT THERE'S NO DATA YET
    }
  }
...
  const openModal = () => {
    console.log("************* Ready to go inside OPEN MODAL FUNCTION", siteDetails);
    if (row.actions.message === true) {
      console.log("************* INSIDE OPEN MODAL FUNCTION");
      titleMsg = 'Messsages for Request ID: ' + row.cfg_header_id;
    } else {
      titleMsg = 'No Messsages for Request ID: ' + row.cfg_header_id;
    }
    modalMessage =
      <ECAMPrompt
        handleClick={handleCancel}
        setDisplayPrompt={setCancelValues}
        messageObj={'There was a problem retrieving the error messages.'}
        close
      />

    return modalMessage;
  }
...
return (
    <div key={`icon-${row.cfg_header_id}`}>
      <span>
        {row.actions.view && <FileIcon className={style.actionIcon} onClick={handleGetCiq} />}
        {row.actions.delete && <RemoveIcon className={style.actionIcon} onClick={handleDelete} />}
        {row.actions.execute && <CDIcon className={style.actionIcon} onClick={handleExecute} />}
        {row.actions.download && !siteDetails && (
          <a
            href={`${config.apiBaseUrl}/routercfg/table/download/${row.cfg_header_id}`}
            target='_blank'
            title='Download'
            rel='noreferrer'
          >
            <DownloadIcon className={style.actionIcon} />
          </a>
        )}
        **// THIS IS MY CODE that's NOT WORKING not opening!**
        {row.actions.message && (
          <ModalPortal>
            <Modal title={titleMsg} handleHideModal={() => setCancelValues(false)}>
              modalMessage // THIS IS THE MODAL MESSAGE I want to send... but...
            </Modal>
          </ModalPortal>,
          <BookIcon className={style.actionIcon} onClick={handleGetMessages} />
        )}
        {row.actions.download && siteDetails && row.status.toLowerCase() === 'success' && (
          <a
            href={`${config.apiBaseUrl}/routercfg/table/download/${row.cfg_header_id}`}
            target='_blank'
            title='Download'
            rel='noreferrer'
          >
            <DownloadIcon className={style.actionIcon} />
          </a>
        )}
        {siteDetails && row.status.toLowerCase() === 'success' && (
          <UploadIcon className={style.actionIcon} onClick={handleUpload} />
        )}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
TableActions.propTypes = {
  row: PropTypes.object,
  userId: PropTypes.string,
  setShowCIQ: PropTypes.func,
  setCancelValues: PropTypes.func,
  setShowMessageModal: PropTypes.func,
  showCIQ: PropTypes.string,
  userItentialMessages: PropTypes.string,
  siteDetails: PropTypes.bool,
  task: PropTypes.instanceOf(Map),
  showConfigModal: PropTypes.object
}
```

**UPDATE**: I tried putting AWAIT before getMessages(), but I get this in VSCode, and it has no effect

[image: AWAIT has no affect]

**UPDATE 2:**

So, I redid the function for getMessages

```
export function getSomeMessages(requestId) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(config.ajax.get(`/routercfg/table/requests/${requestId}/messages`).then(res => res.data || []))
  })
}
```

But when I call it in my other code it still won't allow async or await...

**UPDATE 3:**

Good news! I got the call to the function pinging BEFORE the openModal function.   My only remaining issue is:

1. opening the modal
2. displaying the JSON in the modal

The messagObj contains the JSON with two objects.

Here's my modified code for the Modal

```
        {row.actions.message && (
          <ModalPortal>
            <Modal title={titleMsg} handleHideModal={() => setCancelValues(false)}>
              messageObj <--- THIS IS NOW POPULATED but is it coded correctly?
            </Modal>
          </ModalPortal>,
          <BookIcon className={style.actionIcon} onClick={handleGetMessages} />
        )}
```

Comment: Make sure that getMessages is not async if it is async try using await . that way the code won't move on until the promise is fulfilled

Comment: I tried but I get this error when I put AWAIT before getMessages - see UPDATE

Comment: maybe getMessages calls an async function but it itself isn't asynchronous so check the function tree

Comment: I will stand by

Comment: No! It's NOT Is FUNC ASYNC?  Function which is getMessages.constructor.name

Comment: Whats `useMutation`. A Custom hook or from a 3rd party library ?

Comment: Yeah, I work for a telecom that uses a company that made their own stuff. basically getMessages is the same as calling getSomeMessages but think of it as an alias

Comment: I'm looking at this example SIMPLE REACT MODAL! https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-a-simple-modal-component-with-react-16decdc111a6  - then all I need to do is pass the OBJEVCT with the JSON that's coming back. See UPDATE 3